# Rendering a partial multiple times with jQuery from select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have a select menu where the user can choose a product.

```
%fieldset
      %legend
        Select a Product
      %ul.input_group
        %li
          %label{:for => "product"}
            Product
          %select#product
            %option
              Please Select
            %option
              2 recipients for $65
            %option
              4 recipients for $100
            %option
              8 recipients for $150
```

If a user selects <kbd>2 recipients for $65</kbd>, I would like to load the partial located at `/transcripts/products/recipients/select-recipient` twice into the div `#recipient-list`. Another words I want to do this:

```
#recipient-list
  .recipient
    ...
  .recipient
    ...
```

If other options are selected I would like this div to respond with the appropriate number of items.

How would I go about writing the JQuery for this?

Comment: I'm guessing it is some sort of .replace each time to get the right number and not just add to.

Comment: I've been hacking it together by having different partials with different amounts of recipients but that hardly seems sustainable. I'm having hard time finding a good way to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#product option:selected').each(function(index, product)) {
  $('#recipient-list').append($.get('/transcripts/products/recipients/select-recipient/' + product.val()));
}
```

Then change your options to the following

```
%fieldset
  %legend
    Select a Product
  %ul.input_group
    %li
      %label{:for => "product"}
        Product
      %select#product
        %option
          Please Select
        %option{value: "2"}
          2 recipients fo $65
        %option{value: "4"}
          4 recipients for $100
        %option{value: "8"}
          8 recipients for $150
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for something like this:

```
 $('#product').on('change', function() {
     var val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
     if (val < 1) {
         $('#recipient-list').empty();
         return;
     }

     $('#recipient-list').load('/transcripts/products/recipients/select-recipient',
         function() {
             var copy = $(this).children().clone();
             while (val-- > 1) {
                 $('#recipient-list').append(copy);
             }
         }
     );
 });
```